# Get Unique System Identifiers in C#

Tags: c#

what kind of 'unique' system identifiers can be easily obtained using C# (to hash and then uniquely identify a system)? I could just hash HDD size and things like that but I need to identify and distinguish computers that are all built by the same components so I can't go by that.

Appreciate hints, ideas, sample code!

Comment: I'd be careful with this, that you don't make your customers hate you. They should be able to change network cards, hard disks, and memory size without telling you about it.

Comment: Oh, this requirement does actually come *from* the customer :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a good start with [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.aspx) ...

```
// Win32_CPU will work too
var search = new ManagementObjectSearcher( "SELECT * FROM Win32_baseboard" );
var mobos = search.Get();

foreach (var m in mobos)
{
  var serial = m["SerialNumber"]; // ProcessorID if you use Win32_CPU
}
```

You can do that with many pieces of hardware and come up with a solution.

Comment: I tried that ... but I see that these are days none of the serial nos are being maintained. Mother Board, Processor ... MAC is being changed by changing NIC ... what to choose?

Comment: As the Win32_BaseBoard SerialNumber doesn't return a value in most cases anymore, your best bet is ProcessorID in Win32_Processor

Comment: Note that ProcessorID is equal for all processors of the same type. If you test two i7-FooBar processors, both will have the same ID.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [System.Management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.aspx) namespace to get all stuff related to the hardware, ProcessorId, MAC addresses, and a lot more info you can then hash together.

Take a look at this article:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/GetHardwareInformation.aspx

Comment: To expand on the this and other answers a little bit:

The MAC address of the network card(s) is going to be unique, even if the machines all use the same components. I would start with that.

Second of all, you should be able to get motherboard and CPU serial numbers, as JP said. 

Those, plus the MAC address of physical NICs, should be easily enough to uniquely identify a machine. Just be aware that all of those can change if parts are replaced.

Comment: The MAC address of a network card can be set by software, so you cannot count on it being unique. On the other hand, I think main disk  + mac address + processorId + motherboard could be a safe bet.

Answer (score 6):

Presuming you are talking about Windows, then each Windows installation has a unique product id (which you can see when you view the properties of My Computer). I think this is stored in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion:ProductId(REG_SZ)`. I take it you want more than that?

Comment: What about when the Windows OS image is copied into another computer? Will this registry key be the same on the clone machine?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582%28VS.85%29.aspx) with C# to get quite a bit of information about hardware.

Hard Disk IDs and Ethernet MAC Address are two common unique identifiers used in system identification schemes.  The MAC Address is, in theory, unique per network card.

Comment: In theory, but in practice there is no single unique id that could be used, given that there are tons and easily accessible, it's best to grab two or three and combine them to create a unique string (or hash)

Comment: Yes, I agree.  That's why the "in theory" :)

Answer (score 2):

You could look into using [GUID's](http://www.csharpfriends.com/Articles/getArticle.aspx?articleID=335)

### What is a GUID

For those of you who don't know, a GUID (pronounced goo'id - Globally unique identifier) is a 128-bit integer that can be used to uniquely identify something. You may store users or products in your database and you want somehow uniquely identify each row in the database. A common approach is to create a autoincrementing integer, another way would be to create a GUID for your products.

### How to create a GUID in C#

The GUID method can be found in the System namespace. The GUID method System.Guid.NewGuid() initializes a new instance of the GUID class.

There are also a few overloads available for those of you who want the GUID formatted in a particular fashion.

The following live sample will output the GUID generated, the source code is also below.

```
Response.Write(@"<br>System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString() = " + System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
Response.Write(@"<br>System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString(""N"") = " + System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"));
Response.Write(@"<br>System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString(""D"") = " + System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString("D"));
Response.Write(@"<br>System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString(""B"") = " + System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString("B"));
Response.Write(@"<br>System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString(""P"") = " + System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString("P"));
```

Comment: +1 The Microsoft implementation of GUIDs uses the MAC address and the current time, so they're pretty much a guarenteed way of creating identifiers that will be unique per computer.

Comment: I think the link is broken

Comment: @AndersFinnJørgensen - Thanks, I've pulled the contents of the link into the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Network card MAC address:

```
foreach (NetworkInterface ni in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
{
    // probably need to do some filtering on ni.NetworkInterfaceType here
    Console.WriteLine(ni.GetPhysicalAddress());
}
```

Comment: while this is a good idea, i thingk it would fail if the system does not have NIC!

Comment: This is not a good idea, Because This id changes when user disables a connection or if a software installs a virtual connection