# Uniquely identifying a computer using .NET/Mono?

Tags: c#, .net, mono, guid

I need a way to uniquely identify a computer using .NET that works in both Windows and Linux.

The methods used in both operational system do not have to be the same. That is: I can have an approach for Mono running on Linux and another approach for .NET running on Windows.

I took a look at another [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308956/get-unique-system-identifiers-in-c) on SO and it seems that the default way to identify the computer with .NET is using WMI, but will that work in a Mono machine whatever the OS is?

I'm open to suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I'm in the middle of getting one of our C#/.Net applications to work on Linux...  So I know what you're going through, having to find ways to get around the differences between Linux and Windows.

Now this is very, very hacky, and this is just a rough draft I threw together for you.  There's probably a better way to do it, but maybe it will give you an idea...

```
bool IsRunningMono()
{
    // With our application, it will be used on an embedded system, and we know that
    // Windows will never be running Mono, so you may have to adjust accordingly.
    return Type.GetType("Mono.Runtime") != null;
}

string GetCPUSerial()
{
    string serial = "";

    if(IsRunningMono())
    {
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.FileName = "lshw";
        startInfo.Arguments = "-xml";
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

        using(Process p = Process.Start(startInfo))
        {
            p.WaitForExit();
            System.Xml.XmlDocument xdoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();

            xdoc.Load(new System.Xml.XmlTextReader(new StringReader(p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd())));

            System.Xml.XmlNodeList nodes = xdoc.SelectNodes("node/node/node/serial");

            if (nodes.Count > 0)
            {
                serial = nodes[0].InnerText;              
            }
        }        
    }
    else
    {
       // process using wmi
    }

    return serial;
}
```

I tried loading it into a DataSet instead of an XmlDocument, but it failed every time.  Tested on Ubuntu 9.10.  Hope this gets you going in the right direction.

Comment: Just check for http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.operatingsystem.platform.aspx instead of Type.GetType("Mono.Runtime").

Answer (score 1):

No, WMI will not work on Mono.

Answer (score 1):

Would getting the [MAC address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218284/read-mac-address-from-network-adapter-in-net) work?