# How to get HWID in Lua/C#?

Tags: c#, lua, hwid, fivem

I'm working on a Anti Cheat for FiveM, and I would like to be able to exclude users by using their HWID, so is there a way to get a HWID in lua? If not, how could I be able to get the HWID in C#?

If possible, it would really help me if it was in lua, since I'm not good at C#.

Thanks, Ossie

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get Unique System Identifiers in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308956/get-unique-system-identifiers-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @ChrᴉzsupportsMonica it helps, thanks. However if possible to get in Lua, it would be appreciated :D

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this in lua try this native `GetPlayerToken` ([GetPlayerToken native](https://docs.fivem.net/natives/?_0x54C06897))